# How to set up Flow type declarations - lint up with error "not defined"?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, flowtype

I just got started with typed JS and currently am just exporting/importing my types around. After looking a few things up, I think the proper solution seems to be the idea of "declarations".

After reading [https://flowtype.org/docs/declarations.html#pointing-your-project-to-declarations], I attempted the ".flowconfig"-style.

**decls/types.js**

```
declare type Post = {
  feed: Connection,
}

declare type Connection = {
  edges: Array<Edge>,
  pageInfo: PageInfo,
}

declare type Edge = {
  cursor: number,
  node: Node,
}

declare type PageInfo = {
  endCursor: number,
  hasNextPage: boolean,
}

declare type Node = {
  id: string,
  createdAt: number,
}
```

Then I added the `decls/` directory to my `.flowconfig` `[libs]`.

**.flowconfig**

```
[libs]
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-interface.js
node_modules/react-native/flow
flow/
decls/
```

However all of the types lint up with error not defined e.g. 'Connection' is not defined.

Is there something I missed?

Comment: Are you using ESLint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using ESLint, you need to add the [eslint-plugin-flowtype](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype) extension and minimally enable the [`define-flow-type`](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype#define-flow-type) rule in order for ESLint to not mark Flow types as undefined.

ESLint config:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "flowtype"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "flowtype/define-flow-type": 2
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was it! That didn't occur to be considering the types are defined if you put them in the same file, but not the declarations where the plugin/rule seems to be needed. I also had to restart Atom after installing the plugin, I believe. Thanks a bunch!